# emacs switch from Shell to gdb or pdb mode

Tags: c++, python, emacs, gdb

Let's say I have an open gdb or pdb session in an emacs shell.  So the major mode is "Shell:run"  Now I want to convert that buffer to gdb or pdb (python debugger) major mode.

I tried M-X gud-mode and that switched the mode to "Debugger:run".  But it does not actually work; for example when I type "up", "down", or "n" it does not pop another window up showing the code (trying it under pdb).

So how can I kick emacs into its debugger mode for a session that is already open?

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is source code line tracking, my emacs does pdb source line tracking in `M-x shell` buffers just fine.  No need to enable any other mode.

Comment: Really?  Mine is not doing it.  Can you do Ctrl-x <space> to set a breakpoint?  This is the error I get when I do that: <br/> Command: break frame.py:806
gud-basic-call: Current buffer has no process

Comment: No, that's what I meant by "source code line tracking", `M-x shell` buffers just show the source next to the buffer.